# Testing manual transactions inside Django unittests

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

How do you test code that disables [autocommit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.set_autocommit) and uses savepoints, inside a Django unittest?

The default Django unittest class wraps all tests inside an `@atomic` decorator, which is usually exactly what you want, to ensure the sqlite database gets reset between tests. However, any code that touches `transaction.set_autocommit()` from a test throws the error:

```
TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.
```

even if it works fine outside the unittest.

How do you temporarily disable the transaction autocommit in a unittest, so you can test manual commits?

Comment: I am not entirely sure this works in tests, but try adding a 
`@transaction.commit_on_success` decorator to the test function

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas That decorator was removed several versions ago and is not available to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TransactionTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase):

> `TransactionTestCase` and `TestCase` are identical except for the manner in which the database is reset to a known state and the ability for test code to test the effects of commit and rollback: A `TransactionTestCase` resets the database after the test runs by truncating all tables. A `TransactionTestCase` may call commit and rollback and observe the effects of these calls on the database.